# I´ve got some errors in my code, what can i do?(I am programming whit python 3.10)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, module, webdriver-manager

I was doing a program that consisted of through these modules below create a new page on google, but it was not possible, because of some errors.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

servico=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
navegador=webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
```

This was the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Francisco\\trabalhos que não são da escola\\programação\\projeto1\\teste.py", line 2, in \<module\>
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
File "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\webdriver_manager\\chrome.py", line 7, in \<module\>
from webdriver_manager.drivers.chrome import ChromeDriver
File "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\webdriver_manager\\drivers\\chrome.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from packaging import version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
```

I tried to reinstall all including "packaging" again but it didn´t work too.

What can I do?

Comment: Maybe install packaging too

Comment: I tried but it didn´t work too

Comment: To beggin with, you should be more precise with the title your question. Then give more details. What Python version are you using?

Comment: I am using the version 3.10 of python

Comment: Your problem is with `from packaging import version` while the code you shared does not contain such line at all...

Comment: What i have to do? @Prophet

Comment: Does your code contain the line appearing in the error trace? If yes - please share your actual code

Comment: No, my code is literally all I put in this post.

Comment: What else can I do? @Prophet

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem.
First I changed the editor from Visual studio Code to Pycharm.
After that I instaled the packages that Pycharm asked for, and to solve the big problem of `from packaging install version` I just did `pip install packaging` and `pip install version`, after that i just wrote the line of the error `from packaging install version`. And it worked!

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess here.
So, I guess your problem is with `ChromeDriverManager`.
Try getting rid from it.
To do so, manually download the proper version of `hromedriver.exe` and make your code pointing to that file explicitly.
As following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
```

`C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe` here is the actual location where I have `chromedriver.exe` on my PC

Comment: How can I discover the location of my `chromedriver.exe`?

Comment: You will know that once you have manually downloaded it to your computer

Comment: Create dedicated folder for it and put it there

Comment: I have to uninstall webdrivermanager manually or whit that code the PC or with that code it uninstalls itself?

Comment: what´s the site of chromedriver?

Comment: If you do not call webdrivermanager it will not cause problems

Comment: Google: chrome driver download latest version...

Comment: Another error: `  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Francisco\trabalhos que não são da escola\programação\projeto1\teste2.py", line 9
    webdriver_service = Service('C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32.zip\chromedriver.exe')
                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249365/discussion-between-francisco-frieza-and-prophet).

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following commands in the terminal:
First:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Second:

```
pip install packaging
```

If this doesn't help, try to reinstall the webdriver_manager package:
First:

```
pip uninstall webdriver_manager
```

Second:

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

Comment: It didn't work too

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of how you run webdriver_manager and a screenshot of how you run your teste.py?

Comment: I already solved my problem

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I don't know, but the solution was write `from packaging import version`